# Database help, one table & multiple users, where CRUD permission depends on column value used

Tags: sql-server, database-design, triggers

I'm developing a call ticketing system for a hospital, where multiple users from different branches do CRUD activity on one table. This table has relationship restricted value column called, let say `[BranchId]`. There are three different type of users,

A. **Ticket Manager** (where they can CRUD without restriction),

B. **Ticket Issuer** (where they can issue/view/delete tickets but they can't resolve)

C. **Ticket Resolver** (where they can view/resolve/delete tickets but they can't issue).

So for example,

1. A patient, who has an appointment with `[BranchId]` `1`, calls to the hospital, and wants to cancel their appointment,
2. A Ticket Issuer answers the phone and adds this event onto the ticket table and assigns it to `[BranchId]=1`.
3. Then the colleagues who work on `[BranchId]=1` (they can only see dataset with `[BranchId]=1`) views the data and resolves (sets the `[IsResolved]` column to `1`)
4. The patient gets a phone call to notify that their appointment was cancelled.

Solutions so far I can think of

**Table Triggers**:-
The **Ticket Manager** adds all users into a table, let say called `[BranchUsers]` and this table as a column called `[Username]` where this is populated with `Domain\Username`, `[IsIssuer]`, `[IsResolver]` and `[BranchId]`. The ticket table now has a CRUD trigger when it checks if `SYSTEM_USER` can issue/resolve and their branch. A separate `View` table would be used to select from the ticket table with `INNER JOIN` on `[BranchId]` for the `SYSTEM_USER`. However, the problem with this approach is that users can select data directly from the ticket table and so be able to read everything in the table and the `[BranchUsers]` table may be hard to maintain but that is ok.

**Using Active Directory Group**:-
So in the Windows Server AD Group, create a group called, let say `[Branch1Users]`, `[Branch2Users]` etc..., and create multiple ticket tables... you see now it got complex as if one table need some changing such as renaming a column, then the .NET Core API references need too and going back to the Trigger approach above seems easier.

So what would you think be best, please advice anything even if you think it might not help as it                   may help create a light bulb ideas, I will start the trigger approach for now as this project has deadline soon :-)

Specs that might help:-
Microsoft SQL Server 2019
Windows Server 2019

Comment: I read your wall of text but regardless, triggers are your _last choice_ for implementing logic. The short answer is probably row level security.

Comment: You didn't actually state a problem. If the problem is that certan people should only read/write certain rows based on a data field and login, then row level security will cover that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: That is the best answer Nick.McDermaid (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1690193/nick-mcdermaid). Thank you for your help. I found this image self descriptive for row level security, last accessed on 22 Aug 2021, https://www.sqlshack.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/row-level-security-in-sql-server-illustration.png. Thanks for editing the question, it is much better now :-).

Comment: So now give it a try and when you run into problems, ask a question and we can help.

Comment: You are a STAR (Nick.McDermaid). Thank you.